# How to make Excel UserForm only show up once when based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Cells in Column B are drop-down lists. So if someone selects "Reminder" in cell B2 then the UserForm will show up. I want this to happen for each cell in Column B. My code below accomplishes this, however, the UserForm continues to pop up each time I click around in excel. Even if I already submitted the data in my UserForm. How do I get this to work only once for each cell that has the value of "Reminder" but maintain the ability to have the form show if other cells are entered in as a "Reminder". If B2 is the only one entered in as a "Reminder" I don't want the form to keep showing up each time I move around the sheet. This is my first foray into UserForms so I hope my question makes sense. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("B:B")
    If cell.Value = "Reminder" Then
       UserForm1.Show
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use `Worksheet_Change` instead:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Value = "Reminder" Then UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```